# Trouble handling Expression.Error: Column in Power Query

Tags: sorting, expression, powerquery, datasource, excelquery

I use Power Query to bring the figures from 24 excel file that are stored in SharePoint in different folders, the files had the same structure, the sheets contains my data source hasn't "header",so all file starts with data (in order to avoid having 24 headers when the power query brings all data together).

I have sync all the SharePoint folder to my computer, then I create the "rules" in Power Query, if I refresh data formy computer is work, but when the other users (with same rights and settings) make the refresh of data, it appears the Expression.Error: column

The 11 columns hasn't name in all 24 files, so I don't understand why for the others 10 columns there are not a problem, but with 1 column it returns this error.

has anyone had this error? how can i fix it?

Comment: can you share the M code transforming the single file? as for the header - if all the fiels have header you can use `Use First Row As Headers` functionality and it shouldn't mix them with data

Comment: *"has anyone had this error?"* Since no one here is running your query in your environment, it is highly unlikely. And since we don't even know what your query is, it is unlikely anyone will be able to reproduce it.  I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then **edit your question** to provide enough information so someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @Stachu this is the code form transforming the single file: '= (Paramètre1 as binary) => let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(Paramètre1, null, true),
        Formula_Sheet = Source{[Item="Formula",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Autres colonnes supprimées" = Table.SelectColumns(Formula_Sheet,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11"})
    in
        #"Autres colonnes supprimées"'

Comment: See what you get if you remove the Table.SelectColumn() step.